# remove element from array list and update tab size in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have this simple program I need to remove `element` form the array list and update the size in the loop.

`dist` `fin` and `tab2` are an `arrays lists`

```
int k=2;
int count =0;

int temp,num;//lets say this 2 vars are known and positive 

while (k > 0){
    while(count < dist.size()){

        double num=dist.get(count);

        if (temp>num){
        temp = num;
        }
        count++;
    }

    int e = dist.indexOf(temp);   
    fin.add(tab2.get(e));
    dist.remove(e);

   System.out.print(fin);
   System.out.print(dist);
   System.out.print(dist.size());

   k--;
}
```

This is giving me only one iteration and then it stops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish your inner loop to be executed more than once, you must reset `count` to 0 :

```
while (k > 0) {
    count = 0;
    temp = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while(count < dist.size()){
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Without resetting count to 0, the inner loop won't be executed more than once, since `count < dist.size()` will be false after the first iteration.

EDIT:

It looks like `temp` may also have to be reset before each iteration of the inner loop.

Comment: tank you ill try this

Comment: still having the probleme only one iteration and all stop

Comment: @special Are you sure there's just one iteration? Perhaps the second iteration doesn't modify the list, which makes you think there was only one iteration.

Comment: the problem is that the array list `fin` Whatever i change the  `k` its get filled with one element only

Comment: @Eran ``dist`` has ``dist.size()`` elements

Comment: @Eran `dist` contain 11 elements and i need to use in the 2nd iteration only the rest of the `dist` without the removed element

Comment: @special It looks like you are searching for the smallest number in the list, and store it in `temp`, and then remove it from the list. But you don't reset `temp`, so it will try to remove the same number in the next iteration. Try to reset `temp` to a large number before the inner loop.

Comment: @ Eran tanks a lot for your help now works 100/100 tank you so much